# Sum is not done if joined table is empty with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables structure and trying to make a report from these:

___BillableDatas

```
|--------|------------|---------|--------------|------------|
| BIL_Id | BIL_Date   |BIL_Rate | BIL_Quantity | BIL_Status |
|--------|------------|---------|--------------|------------|
|      1 | 2018-03-01 |     105 |            1 |    charged |
|      2 | 2018-03-01 |      15 |            2 | notcharged |
|      3 | 2018-03-01 |       5 |            1 | notcharged |
|--------|------------|---------|--------------|------------|
```

___SalesTaxes

```
|--------|--------------|------------|
| STX_Id | STX_TaxeName | STX_Amount |
|--------|--------------|------------|
|      8 |        Tax 1 |      5.000 |
|      9 |        Tax 2 |     15.000 |
|--------|--------------|------------|
```

*STX_Amount is a percentage.*

___ApplicableTaxes

```
|-----------|-----------|
| ATX_BILId | ATX_STXId |
|-----------|-----------|
|         1 |         8 |
|         1 |         9 |
|-----------|-----------|
```

- ATX_BILId is the item ID link with ___BillableDatas.
- ATX_STXId is the tax ID link with ___SalesTaxes.

---

I need to get to sum of the items per day
  - without tax
  - with tax

So mething like this:

```
|------------------|---------------|------------|
| BIL_RateNonTaxed | BIL_RateTaxed | BIL_Status |
|------------------|---------------|------------|
|           105.00 |        126.00 |    charged | <- Taxes #8, #9 applicable
|            35.00 |         35.00 | notcharged | <- No taxes here
|------------------|---------------|------------|
```

---

Explications on the totals:

- 105 = `105*1` -- (total of the charged item multiply by the quantity)
- 35 = `(15*2)+5` -- (total of the notcharged items multiply by the quantity)
- 126.00 = `105+(105*(5+15)/100)`
- 35.00 = as no taxe, put the non taxed value.

---

My last try was this one:

```
SELECT BIL_Status
    , SUM(BIL_Rate*BIL_Quantity) BIL_RateNonTaxed
    , IFNULL(SUM((BIL_Rate*BIL_Quantity)+(BIL_Rate*BIL_Quantity*total_sales_tax/100)), SUM(BIL_Rate*BIL_Quantity)) BIL_RateTaxed 
    FROM 
    ( SELECT b.*
            , SUM(t.STX_Amount) total_sales_tax 
        FROM ___BillableDatas b 
        LEFT JOIN ___ApplicableTaxes bt 
            ON bt.ATX_BILId = b.BIL_Id 
        LEFT JOIN ___SalesTaxes t 
            ON t.STX_Id = bt.ATX_STXId 
        GROUP  
            BY ATX_BILId
     ) x
GROUP 
    BY BIL_Status
```

This query works just when each item has a linked taxe (case of my item #1). When item has no linked taxes (item #2 and #3), the sum is not made.

Please see this SQLFiddle to help you if needed:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/433a3f/2

The only one error with the link is I should have `35` and not `30`.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you want to handle a missing value for STX_Amount as a zero.  Maybe handle that in the outer query, a wrapper around `total_sales_tax` ... for example `IFNULL(total_sales_tax,0)`. (that's just a guess, a common gotcha with null values, I haven't really examined the total problem.)

Comment: Hello @spencer7593, by doing this, the sum is not done too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery was grouping by the wrong thing.  You are grouping by ATX_BILId, but I think you really wanted to get all the unique billable data bill_ids.  At least the following query returns what you expected.  The only difference is changing "GROUP BY ATX_BILId" to "GROUP BY BIL_Id"

```
SELECT BIL_Status
    , SUM(BIL_Rate*BIL_Quantity) BIL_RateNonTaxed
    , IFNULL(SUM((BIL_Rate*BIL_Quantity)+(BIL_Rate*BIL_Quantity*total_sales_tax/100)), SUM(BIL_Rate*BIL_Quantity)) BIL_RateTaxed 
    FROM 
    ( SELECT b.*
            , SUM(t.STX_Amount) total_sales_tax 
        FROM ___BillableDatas b 
        LEFT JOIN ___ApplicableTaxes bt 
            ON bt.ATX_BILId = b.BIL_Id 
        LEFT JOIN ___SalesTaxes t 
            ON t.STX_Id = bt.ATX_STXId 
        GROUP  
            BY BIL_Id
     ) x
GROUP 
    BY BIL_Status
```

[Link to SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/433a3f/26)

In general, when you are troubleshooting this type of query, the first thing to do is examine the returned rows without the group bys.  It becomes easier to see the problem when you run the following query.

```
SELECT BIL_Status, 
     BIL_Rate,
     BIL_Quantity,
     total_sales_tax
    FROM 
    ( SELECT b.*
            , SUM(t.STX_Amount) total_sales_tax 
        FROM ___BillableDatas b 
        LEFT JOIN ___ApplicableTaxes bt 
            ON bt.ATX_BILId = b.BIL_Id 
        LEFT JOIN ___SalesTaxes t 
            ON t.STX_Id = bt.ATX_STXId 
        GROUP  
            BY ATX_BILId
     ) x
```

Comment: Hello! Your query looks working. Give me time to full test it please. Thanks.